# Resultado de PHP dentro de um modal com CSS

Tags: php, css, modal

Olá, eu estou tentando colocar o resultado de um quiz feito apenas com PHP e um pouco de JS(usado somente para esconder a pergunta anterior e mostrar a proxima) dentro de um modal, feito apenas com HTML e CSS, pois estou construindo um site no qual tenho somente HTML, PHP e CSS disponiveis.
Aqui está o que tenho até o momento:

```
$totalcerto = 0;

if ($resposta1 == "B") { $totalcerto++; }
if ($resposta2 == "D") { $totalcerto++; }
if ($resposta3 == "A") { $totalcerto++; }
if ($resposta4 == "B") { $totalcerto++; }
if ($resposta5 == "A") { $totalcerto++; }

echo "$totalcerto / 5 respostas corretas";
```

?>

este é meu PHP, gostaria que essa variável $totalcerto aparecesse dentro de um modal, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Use o Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Você já conseguiu fazer o modal aparecer?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro crie seu modal com HTML e CSS, e deixe-o oculto, suponho que você já saiba fazer isso, caso não saiba é só perguntar que posto o código.

Depois de ter criado sua variável php *$totalcerto* como fez acima, coloque o seguinte JS:

```
document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = "<?PHP echo $totalcerto; ?>";
```

**Importante**

Esse JS precisa estar no final do body ou no evento onload, caso contrário a div com a id modal ainda não existirá, portanto será retornado *undefined*. Aí é só criar uma função pra mostrar o modal quando o usuário terminar o quiz.

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta é meio antiga, mas vamos lá.

Primeiro, aconselho o uso do bootstrap, o que já vai facilitar bastante seu trabalho. Após colocar os arquivos na pasta e criar as referências deles no seu arquivo crie um modal(pode ser no final da página) com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"> <!-- Esse modal já é oculto-->
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Na estrutura html acima, coloque seu contéudo php (no caso $totalcerto) dentro da tag div com class = 'modal-body', use o php do jeito normal, como você usaria numa página html qualquer.

Para chamar o modal, bastar criar dentro da tag `<head>` esse script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     $('#myInput').focus();
   })
})
</script>
```

> Só uma observação, o seu código php parece não estar eficiente, porque
>   se você tiver umas 10 perguntas, você teria que repetir esse código 10
>   vezes para que sua variável $totalcerto pudesse somar a quantidade de
>   acertos